# How to get rid of white artifacts on the edge when rendering with Eevee DoF

Tags: eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

This ugly lights appear in every shot taken with Eevee in dark light condition and a visible F-stop.
I made a super easy file to demonstrate it:
https://easyupload.io/omaibj

This is the shot with and without DoF:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have "Contact Shadows" enabled on your lights?

Comment: yes with 0.4 distance.. makes no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enabling "Jitter Camera" under *Render Properties > Depth of Field*:

[image: Jitter]

You may want to increase the "Over Blur" as well. Keep in mind, I am aware this is not an ideal solution - there are several tags regarding EEVEE DOF problems on *developer.blender.org*, it might take me some time to get through them, and there may indeed not be a perfect solution yet.

Comment: This is actually working to reduce the artifacts and may be a solution for other people experiencing the same problem.
But in the scene I'm working there are a lot of refraction and "Jitter Camera" creates way too much noise (also increases rendering time quite a bit).

Comment: Yeah. I know it's not ideal. Could it be related to this? - https://developer.blender.org/T86578     It's also mentioned here, but Jitter Camera is the only proposed solution - https://developer.blender.org/T90216

Comment: After several renders I can say the jitter works good enough . To get rid of the noise I had to push the the override blur until 50-70%. If you then go over, up to 100% it seems to bring back the "white ghost".